# Drupal: expand menu if node url is in menu-item

Tags: drupal

I've got menu:

London
--Home
--News(shows all London news. Path is /london/news/)
--About
NewYork
--Home
--News(shows all NY news. Path is /ny/news/)
--About

Normally, when i click on News menu-item in London it shows all new related to London. And menu expands. But when I click to news(/london/news/new123/: menu folds. I want menu always be expanded if node is child of menu-item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Menu Trails module](http://drupal.org/project/menutrails) lets you do that without having to write any code.

Comment: It's good for Drupal 6. But for Drupal 7 I foud [link](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position).Thanks any way!